# What's the difference between mini PCIe and mSATA interfaces and SSDs?

Tags: ssd, msata, minipci

Are they even different at all? I've seen SSDs being sold on the market being tagged with both mSATA and mini PCIe.  I've seen marketing ads that say mini PCIe are better than mSATA which suggests they are two different formats. I'm totally confused.

If they are different, then what is the difference in terms of performance, compatibility, availability, and longevity? Are mSATA SSDs compatible to mini PCIe interfaces? Are mini PCIe SSDs compatible to mSATA interfaces? Are we moving to mSATA or mini PCIe in the future? What are their cons and pros?

Comment: Asus answers it all, maybe this can help: http://rog.asus.com/308552014/labels/guides/ssd-guide-pci-express-m-2-msata-and-sata-express-the-differences-explained/

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I've just lost several days to this subject; it would be best if someone who is actually knowledgeable could confirm the correctness of the following, but AFAIK, this is what I understand is actually going on:

1. mini PCI-Express (mPCIe) and mini SATA (mSATA) are two separate standards. Each standard specifies both a bus and a physical interface. The physical connector and the physical form-factors of the two standards are IDENTICAL -- which I suppose makes the manufacture of these things cheaper (and one might hope, the price). (I say form-factor*s* because there are full-height and half-height versions at least. But careful: you really should use an adapter to put a half-height card into a full-height slot, even though it "fits" just fine. This is because the card NEEDS to be screwed-in for proper contact, and the screw-hole is twice as far away from the half-height card than it needs to be, so you need a plastic adapter that screws in properly and holds-down the half-height card).
2. The connector and form-factors are the same, but the specs of the actual individual PINs only partially coincide. In fact, even within the SINGLE mPCIe specification, there are various options about which pins are actually implemented within a particular card. In fact, it seems that there are even options which enable certain pins to have exactly opposite meanings from card to card!! (To be perfectly truthful, it might be that these opposite meanings are actually a difference between the meaning in mPCIe and in mSATA; because of reason # below, I could not tell. I can only tell you that it seems that in my Lenovo T420, pin 20 on the "mPCIe slot for WLAN cards" causes the card to turn its radio on, while pin 20 in the "mPCIe slot for WWAN cards" causes the card to turn its radio off. Are we having fun yet? It seems that this is done for the explicit purpose of enabling OEMs to limit the utility of certain slots to certain types of cards. So, for example, if you stick the Wifi card from some Lenovo Thinkpads into the WWAN slot, it won't work; but if you take a tiny sliver of scotch tape and cover pin 20 on the Wifi card and then insert it into the WWAN slot, it works just fine )
3. Because the connector and form-factors are the same, you can easily insert cards of one type into either slot. The best analogy I can give is this: Think some big-name branded household appliance that you can buy both in the USA and in France, and that has a detachable power cord. Then imagine that you switch the cords on one of them, so both appliances now have the same plug. Next remove any markings or labels that would enable you to know which one was which. Finally, have someone blindfold you (put stoppers in your ear, etc.) fly you blind to one of the two countries, and bring you a room where you can plug in the appliance. Now ask yourself: what will happen if you plug in the appliance and turn it on? It might work just fine; it might work, but only at half-speed or a double-speed; it might immediately short out a fuse somewhere; it might actually burn-out instantly, or even burst into flames within seconds; on the other hand, it might be that what happens is .... nothing at all.
4. The mPCIe spec (at least, I don't know mSATA) specifies that certain pins should carry the signals of OTHER well-known buses. For examples, some of the pins just pass-through USB signals to the USB bus. This is very useful, because it makes it super-cheap to add USB ports onto an mPCIe card. It seems to be possible for a manufacturer to make an "mCPIe slot" that doesn't in fact furnish ANY mPCIe signals at all!!! (It might be there for an optional "mPCIe USB card", for example. The "mPCIe" slot passes through USB signals. This seems to be the case with my Lenovo Thinkpad T420, for example. In fact, there is code in the BIOS which prevents even a regular USB card from working in this slot. The BIOS allows a certain whitelist of WWAN modem cards work in this slot. These cards are in fact just WWAN modems, and connect via the USB pass-through pins of mPCIe).
5. Finally, some manufacturers themselves seem to be either as confused as you and I; or perhaps they're merely disingenuous. My Lenovo T420 has a "mini PCI-Express WWAN slot": the whitelist of cards that work in this slot includes both "mPCIe WWAN cards" (which are pure USB modems, mounted on cards of the mPCIe form-factor and using the USB pass-through signals) and "mSATA storage cards". As far as I can tell, this "mPCIe slot" supports MSATA cards but not actual mPCIe cards (even if you cover pin 20).

I note that unlike my toy thought-experiment with household appliances above, there are no truth-in-advertising or consumer labeling laws that apply to these cards or the marketing materials that describe them. So it might be that you can in fact fry your cards or your motherboard by plugging an "mPCIe card" into an "mPCIe slot". So far, I've been lucky -- things just didn't work, and nothing has been ruined or lost except for my time.

Bottom line is: "yea they look the same, but what happens when you plug a given card into a given slot can only be predicted if there is some explicit documentation about the outcome of that act."

Apologies for the insane length of this post. I guarantee you that it took you less time to read it than it took me to learn the information in it. And writing it allowed me to let off some steam -- to let go and stop thinking about sending white powder in an unmarked envelope to some Lenovo facilities :).

scott

Comment: Welcome.  The way this site is structured, answers are supposed to be definitive so someone can reference it and count on it being correct.  If you are confident this is an accurate answer, leave it and cite the sources you researched.  If you are wrong, it is likely to be downvoted (which would hurt your rep) and/or edited.  If you aren't really sure it is right, post it as a new question asking for confirmation.  Reference this question as related and mention what makes yours different in some respect so it is not flagged as a duplicate.

Comment: *[...] which I suppose makes the manufacture of these things cheaper (and one might hope, the price).* Say what?... I'm sorry but that doesn't make any sense, and you don't have to get technical to see that. Cheaper things (products), **and** cheaper price?...

Comment: @sammyg It makes sense to me. If you reuse or repurpose an existing physical standard, the various manufacturers can use existing resources (CAD files, connectors, sockets, and so on) and the cost of designing and manufacturing the parts goes down. One might hope that the price of the finished products goes down as well because of this optimization. This is what I read in Scott's post and it makes sense.

Comment: proprietariness at its best

Comment: I almost rage quit reading this at the end of point 2. Good answer, though.

Comment: It should be noted that, if you look at the specifications for mSATA and mini-PCIe, the power and ground pins are in the same pin locations and the same voltages.  Also the PCIe data lanes are in the exact same positions as the mSATA data channels and use similar IO standards.  Plugging an mSATA card into a PCIe slot and vice versa might not work, but the chances of actually damaging anything are greatly reduced by the largely compatible pinout.

Answer (score 10):

I found this on [ASUS site](http://rog.asus.com/308552014/labels/guides/ssd-guide-pci-express-m-2-msata-and-sata-express-the-differences-explained/):

> **mSATA SSDs:** The mSATA (mini-SATA) interface appeared briefly for a generation of motherboards (such as the Maximus V series) and notebooks recently. mSATA SSDs follow the SATA specification, offering a maximum performance of 6Gbit/s and look much like mini-PCI-Express devices, but the two connectors are not inter-compatible. mSATA has been phased out an replaced with the better designed M.2."

Answer (score 6):

For people who reach here via google, see here:

https://communities.intel.com/message/205714

and  here:

http://www.intel.com/support/motherboards/desktop/sb/CS-032415.htm?wapkw=032415

Although mini PCIe and mSATA have the same physical connection, mSATA is natively supported in the mini PCIe slot only if the system provides a dedicated SATA controller on the PCIe slot. You can use an adapter to place an mSATA drive in a mini PCIe slot, but you will still need to attach it to a free SATA port (using both the SATA and PCIe slot)

Comment: Only one SATA port is needed

Answer (score 1):

PCIe  is a high-speed serial computer expansion bus. PCIe's have the capability of being compatible with mSATA slots, which is a computer bus interface that connects host bus adapters like PCIe to mass storage devices like SSDs(Solid State Drives)

Comment: But there are some laptops (ultrabooks) like Sony Vaio Pro that offers mini PCIe SSDs.

Comment: Read revisions.

Comment: Perhaps a more elaborated answer would be helpful. Are ALL mSATA SSDs compatibile to mini PCIe slots? Are ALL mini PCIe SSDs compatible to mSATA slots? And if they are different, why some SSDs, like the link I provided, can be BOTH mSATA and mini PCIe at the same time?

Comment: No, not all of the PCIe's are compatible with mSATA slots, and not all mSATAs are compatible with PCIe slots. In fact, they usually aren't. They're both two different types of solid state drives. However, some certain mSATA SSDs are compatible with PCIe slots and vice versa like the one in the Sony Vaio Pro. The differences between mSATA and PCIe's are electrical. Sort of like how some electronics require 5V power and some require 10V power.

Comment: You mean, there are SSDs that are compatible to both mSATA slots and mini PCIe slots?

Comment: Yes, an example would be [this](http://www.amazon.com/Samsung-PCI-E-mSATA-Solid-MZMPA032HMCD/dp/B00B47I00U) or the one in that Sony Vaio Pro you were talking about.